# SUMIF with Google Docs using adiacent cells for the IF

Tags: google-sheets

It's probably easier than what I am thinking, but I cannot find a decent solution.

I simply need to SUM the values of a whole column (let's say C3:C1000) IF and ONLY IF the corresponding cell (in the same row) in column F is EMPTY.

I tried many different solutions, from the "silly"

```
= SUMIF(C3:C1000;"F3=""")
```

to the more complicated

```
= SUMIF(F3:F1000;INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))="";C3:C1000)
```

to no avail (it gives back an error).

PS: I am not an Excel expert, so don't be too harsh ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
SUMIFS(C3:C1000;F3:F1000;"")
```

(done in new spreadsheet)

**EDIT:**
As mentioned, done with new spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12XKQHREslQbyd0sgXj5Ld3iXtAJeVDgqJcFdpCTktzk/edit?usp=sharing

**EDIT N°2**
and with the old spreadsheet format:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ao02g19G1-G-dEtaRzRxMnA0dnlYUllpN2k5RTZPcWc&usp=sharing

the formula change a little:

```
=sumif(F3:F;"";C3:C)
```

Comment: Google Spreadsheet doesn't support (yet?) SUMIFS.
Out of curiosity, I tried it anyway, both as "SUMIFS" and as "SUMIF", getting two different errors ;)